# Touch sensor not working

Tags: c, robotics, nxt

I am attempting to create a very simple program in RobotC. In this program the robot will move forward until the touch sensor is hit.

```
#pragma config(Sensor, S2,     touchSensor,    sensorTouch)

void setMotors(int a, int b){
    motor[motorA] = a;
    motor[motorB] = b;
}

task main(){
    wait1Msec(100);//Wait for sensor to init

    setMotors(50, 50);

    while(sensorValue(touchSensor) == 0){
        //Do Nothing
    }

    setMotors(0, 0);
}
```

This code should make the robot move forward until the touch sensor is triggered.
Whenever I try and do anything with the touch sensor it does not work. When I output the value to the debug log it shows 180 when pressed and 1024 when released. I have verified that it is working normally by viewing the value on the brick itself.

Robot C Version: 4.0

Comment: If what you said is true, you should change the `while` statement to this: `while(sensorValue(touchSensor) == 1024){//Do Nothing }`, right?

Comment: If the sensorValue is never 0, do the motors ever spin?

Comment: @FiddlingBits the problem is the docs say it is either 1 or 0 so thats a problem.

Comment: @AustinMullins they do not ever spin for more than a milisecond. But the problem when I output to debug log it is either 180 or 1024 nothing in between

Comment: Awesome, that's what I'd expect given those values. So, change the while statement to `while(sensorValue(touchSensor) > 500)` and let me know what happens.

Comment: @AustinMullins why is it not outputting 1 or 0?

Comment: Because it's an analog sensor processed by a 10-bit ADC.

Comment: @AustinMullins oh, so its the raw value

Comment: @AustinMullins but why would the documentation say otherwise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58135/discussion-between-austin-mullins-and-noah-huppert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your touch sensor is [stuck in SensorRaw mode](http://www.robotc.net/wiki/NXT_Functions_Sensors#SensorRaw). It is unclear - from the documentation I could find - how this could be fixed in code, but a work-around would be to explicitly put the sensor into raw mode (in case the situation changes in the future), and then compute the boolean value with a function like this:

```
bool sensorIsOn(short sensorRawValue)
{
    bool isOn = false;
    if(sensorRawValue > 512)
    {
        isOn = true;
    }
    return isOn;
}
```